# Disabling a button for page editor for a field based on a certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a set of custom buttons for a field for the page editor, and I want to disable some of them based on a condition when they load. Is there a way to do this? This button was set using the mulitlist option for the 'page editor' when going directly to that field in the template that contains that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a button inside the Page Editor itself (the ribbon), you can override the `QueryState` method for that - have it return false to disable the button, true to enable it.

The method is `public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)`

You could do something like:

```
public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
{
    var field = (MultilistField)context.Items[0].Fields["Fieldname"];
    var selected = field.GetItems();
    // Check whether the correct ones are selected. If so, return true - else false
}
```

You can also hide the buttons - using `CommandState.Hidden`

**[edit]**
I might've misunderstood - if it's buttons for a fieldtype, you might like [this article](http://blog.xcentium.com/2012/07/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field-part-1/). It doesn't show how to hide buttons, but you might be able to do something with the `public override void HandleMessage(Message message)` method to at least ignore it.

**[edit]** 
Another edit, this should allow you to check the field id or name.

You could change or add to the `getChromeData` pipeline. For instance, you could override the `Process` method in the `GetFieldChromeData` class. 
This class generates the buttons defined in the Core database in `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Common field buttons`. Instead of adding all of them you could add the condition there. 
After you get the buttons, you could possibly remove the buttons you don't want based on the Field ID or Field Name, before they get added.

**[Final edit]**
I've written a little more elegant solution than the edit above. You can read it [here](http://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/page-editor-explorations/).
In short, instead of overriding Sitecore code I've added a processor to the pipeline and remove the buttons based on both the title of the field and the value of another field on the same item.

```
public class RemoveButtons : GetChromeDataProcessor
{
    public override void Process(GetChromeDataArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, “args”);
        Assert.IsNotNull(args.ChromeData, “Chrome Data”);

        if (“field”.Equals(args.ChromeType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Field argument = args.CustomData["field"] asField;
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(argument, “CustomData[\"{0}\"]“.FormatWith(new object[] { “field” }));

            if (argument.Name == “Title” && MainUtil.GetBool(argument.Item["NeedsToBeCheckedToPersonalize"], false))
            {
                args.ChromeData.Commands.RemoveAll(delegate(WebEditButton b)
                                {
                                    return b.Header == “Personalize”;
                                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm - the problem is that this is for a text field (sc:text) for the page editor, and I have the same text field in three different places. It seems that only the buttons for the last text field is disabled, because probably they are all the same command.

Comment: Check the final edit - that'll fix the issue of the commands hidden on all fields of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the Sitecore Rules Engine to address this requirement? Take a look at  [Rule-Based User Interface Components for the Sitecore Client](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2012/10/Rule-Based-User-Interface-Components-for-the-Sitecore-Client.aspx) for a detailed explanation of how this can be achieved.